# udev Run commands not running

Tags: udev

I'm trying to create a udev rule to unlock my computer when I connect my phone by USB.  I could not find that that rule was being ran and so I tried a much simpler rule.
This is the rule (anonymized) :

```
KERNEL=="sd?1", ATTRS{idVendor}=="****", ATTRS{idProduct}=="****", SYMLINK+="phone", RUN+="touch /home/user/udev.touch"
```

I know that the rule is running because the link `phone -> sdc1` is being created but the file is not being created.  Are there security setting that I have to enable for the file to run an external program?

Comment: Have you tried using the full path? `/usr/bin/touch`

Comment: I just tried it.  That is now working.  Why does udev not search the path?  and does that mean that I will have to have the full path for every command in the script that I want to run as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must use full path in the RUN key because (`man udev`)

> If no absolute path is given, the program is expected to live in
>   /lib/udev, otherwise the absolute path must be specified. Program name
>   and arguments are separated by spaces. Single quotes can be used to
>   specify arguments with spaces.

Nevertheless the (bash) script itself should behave as normal, that is you don't need to specify the path.

Comment: It seems that only the very simplest of commands works. Scripts don't run either even when the entire path is given

Comment: Please post the full script you're trying to run. Be aware that the script is run as root, not as a regular user.

Comment: I found I had a bad path to bash.  The script on add works now but the remove rule does not run.  I'll ask as a different question.

Answer (score 3):

I've had this issue as well, and I can confirm as of 12.04 you need to specify the full `bash` path and full `bash` script for the RUN command to work.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem with udev. I tried almost everything to get to scripts to work when adding and removing devices.

This is the code I made:

```
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="sda1", SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi", ATTRS{model}=="AVV207-0        ", SYMLINK+="Lacie", MODE="0666", RUN+="/bin/sh /usr/bin/udev/lacie-add.sh", OPTIONS="last_rule"
ACTION=="remove", KERNEL=="sda1", RUN+="/bin/sh /usr/bin/udev/lacie-del.sh", OPTIONS="last_rule"
```

Adding the `OPTIONS="last_rule"` parameter did the trick.