# udev doesn't run bash script as RUN argument

Tags: usb, bash, udev

I'm trying to set a simple script to run whenever a USB storage device is being plugged to the computer. For that task I have a `100-usb.rules` file in `/etc/udev/rules.d` which has a very generic rule:

```
ACTION=="add", RUN+="/usr/local/auto-update.sh"
```

I expect that whenever I plug anything to the computer that script will trigger. The reason the rule is so generic is because doesn't matter what kind of rule I tried the script just NEVER being run.

Now the `/user/local/auto-update.sh` script has a very simple command:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir /tmp/testfolder
```

I've made sure to give execute rights to the script with

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/auto-update.sh
```

after running the command `ls -l /usr/local/auto-update.sh` I get the permissions

```
-rwxr-xr-x
```

The weird thing is that if I alter my rule to look something like

```
ACTION=="add", RUN+="/bin/mkdir /tmp/folder1"
```

Then it is actually going ahead and creating that folder.

I really am lost here... I have NO clue why it's not working!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the output of `ls -l /usr/local/auto-update.sh`. You have only given execute rights to the owner of the file, not everyone.

Comment: @terdon I've edited my post. It seems like the execute right is being granted to everyone

Comment: Rather a workaround, but until you find out why it's not working `/bin/bash /usr/local/auto-update.sh` will probably work

Comment: @kos well, thanks it seems to work now. But it really annoys me as I don't understand what the issue is :/

Comment: I've never used udev rules, but from what I'm reading around it should work with a script (also if it's a shell interpreting the command it should be able to read the shebang at the top and run it regardless), upvoted

Comment: That's very strange. I just tested and it works fine here. Does running the script manually work?

Comment: @terdon Yes. When I run it manually it works

Comment: Try changing the RUN rule to `RUN+="/usr/local/auto-update.sh 2>/tmp/error"`. I'm not sure if that will work but it might give us some debugging information.

Comment: According to [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/161585/380067) answer at some point specifying `bash` path became mandatory, but it doesn't reference any source. I guess the command is not interpreted by a shell, but if it is doing what terdon suggested definetly could give an insight

Comment: @terdon Okay, that's disturbing. I've edited my RUN section and guess what? everything works just fine and there are no errors so the `/tmp/error` file is never being created.

Comment: Was `/tmp/testfolder` created?

Comment: @terdon I changed the script to create a random file in some other location, but yea, it worked

Comment: I wonder if you had some kind of non-printing character in there that was screwing things up. Did you ever edit the script in Windows or something? If you change it back to creating a dir in `/tmp` and it still works, could you delete this question? If it's not reproducible, it's unlikely to help anyone else.

Comment: @terdon It seems like the issue is randomly happening now... until now kos's workaround worked everytime

Comment: @kfirba , try change its name from `100-usb.rules` to `99-usb.rules`

Comment: @kfirba , Could you flag this for closing: off-topic > can't reproduced. I just read your comment on meuh's answer that the initial setup now working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `udev` does not provide a `PATH` in its exported
environment when running scripts.

Add a `PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin` or whatever to the start
of your bash script.

For example, I dumped the env contents when a script of mine was called as a usb key was plugged in and got:

```
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/host4
DEVTYPE=scsi_host
ID_BUS=usb
ID_MODEL=Transcend
ID_MODEL_ENC=Transcend
ID_MODEL_ID=4000
ID_REVISION=0035
ID_SERIAL=TS-RDF5_Transcend_000000000036
ID_SERIAL_SHORT=000000000036
ID_TYPE=scsi
ID_USB_DRIVER=usb-storage
ID_USB_INTERFACES=:080650:
ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=00
ID_VENDOR=TS-RDF5
ID_VENDOR_ENC=TS-RDF5\x20
ID_VENDOR_ID=8564
SEQNUM=2023
SUBSYSTEM=scsi
USEC_INITIALIZED=65380632
```

i.e. no PATH.

Comment: how does that settle with our findings in the question's comment section? that's interesting.

Comment: just caught up with the comments: dont think you can do redirection and shell stuff in the RUN command.

Comment: Ha, that would explain it. @kfirba Try `ACTION=="add", RUN+="/usr/local/auto-update.sh"` and `/bin/mkdir /tmp/testfolder` (or add `PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin` at the top of the script as meuh suggested). Please also let me know if it works so I can upvote this answer

Comment: @kos I'm just not sure if it solved the issue or not since when I reverted all the changes to what I had originally it suddenly started to work :/

Comment: @kfirba I doubt this is the problem.  udev only knows about programs in `/lib/udev` but `bash` is called with its full path in the shebang line and that means it has its own environment, including a path. Try adding an `echo $PATH > /tmp/foo` to your script and you'll see what it has as PATH. In any case, if this is indeed the issue, just change the `mkdir` in your script to `/bin/mkdir`.